# Concatenate several Date Columns and column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

> Actual .CSV datafile.

```
Date    MTM_B7_1    Date    MTM_B7_11   Date    MTM_B7_12
03/01/11 AM 2084    04/01/11 AM -8166   04/01/11 AM -8332
04/01/11 AM -9066   05/01/11 AM 28613   05/01/11 AM -8750
05/01/11 AM 103607  06/01/11 AM 35605   06/01/11 AM -21307
10/01/11 AM 68538   07/01/11 AM 55608   07/01/11 AM 151609
```

A reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('01/03/11',periods=8, format=' %d/%m/%y    %p'),
                    'MTM1': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                    'Date1': pd.date_range('01/07/11',periods=8, format=' %d/%m/%y    %p'),
                    'MTM2': [4, 3, 5, -7, 6, -9, 8, 9]
                    })
```

I have a .csv file in the above format, I want to concatenate all the Date columns and retain the MTM column values as per their respective Date index, and take out rest of the Date columns to have one Date Index for all MTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider splitting dataframe by Date/MTM pairs to a dataframe list and then chain merge outer joins with `reduce()`:

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('01/03/11',periods=8, format=' %d/%m/%y'),
                   'MTM1': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'Date1': pd.date_range('01/07/11',periods=8, format=' %d/%m/%y'),
                   'MTM2': [4, 3, 5, -7, 6, -9, 8, 9]
                  })

# FOR POSTED TWO PAIRING DATA
dfList = [df[['Date', 'MTM1']],
          df[['Date1','MTM2']].rename(columns={'Date1':'Date'})]

# FOR MANY PAIRINGS (ASSUMING ORDER AND MATCHES INTACT)
dfList = [df[[d, m]].rename(columns={d:'Date'})\
                        for d, m in zip([c for c in df.columns if 'Date' in c],
                                        [c for c in df.columns if 'MTM' in c])]

df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'], how='outer'), dfList).set_index('Date')
print(df)

#             MTM1  MTM2
# Date                  
# 2011-01-03   2.0   NaN
# 2011-01-04   3.0   NaN
# 2011-01-05   4.0   NaN
# 2011-01-06   5.0   NaN
# 2011-01-07   6.0   4.0
# 2011-01-08   7.0   3.0
# 2011-01-09   8.0   5.0
# 2011-01-10   9.0  -7.0
# 2011-01-11   NaN   6.0
# 2011-01-12   NaN  -9.0
# 2011-01-13   NaN   8.0
# 2011-01-14   NaN   9.0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the clue as well, actually i was reading a list of DF's and then running a concat after appending the list, which was not needed, as suggested by you by merging the lest itself.

Comment: Great to hear solution worked! If helped, please accept with tick mark to side to confirm resolution.

Comment: Hi thanks for your efforts, here i forgot to mention one more point that is the length of these pairs is variable, so here due to the variable length and  having higher number of pairs, it is merging but also giving other rows, with non matching dates at the end.

Comment: We can change joins from *outer* to *inner*. So you want to keep rows with MTMs in **all** dataframes? Not one single NaNs?

Comment: well, my mistake it's solved, there was an issue with a sort function, thanks